# Hi I am new User for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I want to use ubuntu for my small office with 15 Computers. Which version will be the best as i want monitor all the computers from my computer so that i can see there working progress as will as i can monitor there screen and history of there work for the day and is it possible to kill some process of there computers through my computer and monitor there browsing history or restrict to open few websites.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is the most stable and supported version of Ubuntu for the PC.

See this page for info on how you can monitor your office workspace with Ubuntu.
http://www.ubuntu.com/management